# In Processor Api, will `DefaultStreamPartitioner` be applied when partitioner not specified in `addSink` function ？

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

When I am writing an application using Processor API,  and if I use `addSink` to push logs to downstream topic, logs are not partitioned by their keys.

I debugged step by step, `DefaultStreamPartitioner` is not executed，I did not find comment about sink streamPartitioner in source code .

So will `DefaultStreamPartitioner` be applied when partitioner not specified in `addSink`  function ？

ie:

```
topology
        .addSource("Source", inputTopic)
        .addProcessor("LogToEvents", () -> new LogToEventProcessor(), "Source")
        .addSink("Events-Sink", outputTopic, "LogToEvents");
```

Comment: Note, that `DefaultStreamPartitioner` is not a public class but contained in package `org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals` -- thus, you should not use/rely on it anyway as it might change without notice in any new release (including bug-fix releases).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case `DefaultStreamPartitioner` will not be executed, instead it will use `DefaultPartitioner` `partition(..)` method.
If no partitioner is specified but a key is present, a partition will be chosen using a hash of the key (that logic implemented by `DefaultPartitioner`). If neither key nor partition is present a partition will be assigned in a round-robin fashion.

In class `KafkaProducer` you could find:

`this.partitioner = config.getConfiguredInstance( 
        ProducerConfig.PARTITIONER_CLASS_CONFIG, Partitioner.class);`

and default value is `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner`

And even `DefaultStreamPartitioner` class invokes `partition(..)` method on `DefaultPartitioner` instance, so it's a basic implementation of `StreamPartitioner` which just proxies call to `DefaultPartitioner`.

Comment: Your are right !  I set a breakpoint at  `DefaultPartitioner` `partition(..)`, it is not executed when building topology, but is executed when it is ready to write log to sink topic, thanks!

Comment: `partition(..)` should not be executed during building topology, it only invokes during processing each record.